# Semi transparent image hanging out of a semi transparent div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to build a website header that is semi transparent, and contains a semi transparent image that hangs outside the of the header div, like in the image linked below.

[image: http://imgur.com/ui5WnNT]

Because of overlapping opacities, I can't simply put a semi transparent image in to a semi transparent div and add a negative margin to the image. The best I could come up with was taking the height of the header image, and cutting that bit of the logo image, like in image attached. However that's not ideal, as doesn't play nice responsively etc etc.

[image: http://imgur.com/CBlv8ZB]

Any ideas of how I might achieve this look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can achieve a semi transparent background color with rgba()

Comment: What kind of transparent image do you have for your header background? Is it just one color? Because in that case, you can achieve that by using `background: rgba(x,x,x,.x);`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of your menu then you can place both the logo and the menu inside of a container. Then position the logo with the top value equalling the height of the menu.

```
.header-bg {
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
}

.header-bg .logo {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 10%;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kxBt/1/

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks, flicking through all of the answers now, but that one definitely works. Thanks for your help. Example with image: http://jsfiddle.net/rFkF8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` color format for `background` of both the `.logo` and the `header` to achieve your desired effect. However, you have to give `position: absolute;` to your `.logo` class because it needs to come right below the `header`. If you put your `.logo` on top of your `header`, then colors will overlap and won't look right. So, it needs to starts at the bottom of the `header`.

The `header` should have `position: relative;` so that your `.logo` is positioned relatively to the `header`. This way, you don't even need to know the height of your header because when you define `top` position of your `.logo`, you can simply use `top: 100%` so that it always starts right below your `header`. You don't have to hardcode that `top` value.

Now, you need to shift your actual logo (image) inside your `.logo` on top because its appearing below the `header` right now. For that you can simply push the image by giving it negative `margin-top` value.

**[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fZg58/3/)**

The code would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">
        <img src="/image/path" alt="logo">
    </h1>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  position: relative;
}

.logo { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
}

.logo img {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem and there are a couple ways to solve it; two come immediately to my mind.

The first is your method; carefully position things so that you don't have multiple translucent sections overlapping. This wouldn't be too difficult; if you go with this method I would recommend breaking the header into sections left and right of the image and using absolute positioning.

The second and easier way is to create a version of the picture with the semi-transparent white overlay you desire already applied. Then you can use that as the background for the menu and image. The only tricky thing here is you have to make sure the images line up by either using fixed positioning or calculated pixel offsets. This approach has been around for a long time and you can see any early example (2001-ish) of it [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

My take on it is to create a `:before` pseudo-element.  It has its problems, including what if the logo changes in size at some point, but overall it works.

### HTML

```
<a class="logo" href="#">
    <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" />
</a>
```

### CSS

```
nav a.logo {
  position: relative;
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.0001em;
  font-size: 0.0001em;
}

nav a.logo img {
  position: relative; /* for z-index issues.  giving the image a relative
                         position automatically will place it above the
                         absolutely positioned :before element.  This is
                         because the before element is rendered before the
                         image */
}

nav a.logo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 71px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP6LQ/1/show
Source: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP6LQ/1/

Comment: I like your idea about using :before psuedo element.